# How to add a prefix for each line according to a line field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following file

```
aaa1.bbb1.ccc toto
aaa1.bbb1.ddd. titi
aaa2.bbb2.ccc
aaa2.bbb2.eee tza
aaa2.bbb2.ddd.
```

I want to add at the beginning of each line a string. This string will be "OK" if the first filed of the line finish with `.` and the string will be "NOK" if the first filed of the line do not finish with `.`

The delimiters of the fields is the space

so based on the above example, the ouput of the command will be:

```
NOK aaa1.bbb1.ccc toto
OK aaa1.bbb1.ddd. titi
NOK aaa2.bbb2.ccc
NOK aaa2.bbb2.eee aza
OK aaa2.bbb2.ddd.
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{print ($1 ~ /\.$/ ? "OK" : "NOK"), $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

`awk '{ print $1 ~ /\.$/ ? "OK" : "NOK", $0 }'`

We are saying: for each line, if the first field ends with a period, print OK, otherwise NOK, then print the entire line after that.

Comment: That's the same answer I posted but will cause syntax errors with some awks due to the un-parenthesized ternary expression.

Answer (score 0):

Through `sed`,

```
sed '/.*\. .*/ s/^\(.*\)$/OK \1/g; /\.$/ s/^\(.*\)$/OK \1/g' file | sed '/^[^O]/ s/^\(.*\)$/NOK \1/g'
```

Output:

```
NOK aaa1.bbb1.ccc toto
OK aaa1.bbb1.ddd. titi
NOK aaa2.bbb2.ccc
NOK aaa2.bbb2.eee tza
OK aaa2.bbb2.ddd.
```

Comment: I assumed that the second field doesn't contain dots at the last.

Comment: @EdMorton Both `sed` would fail for a line like `aaa1.bbb1.ddd titi.`. You're `awk` solution is surely the way to go. One possible way with `sed` would be `sed -r '/^[^ ]+\.( |$)/{ba};s/^/NOK /;b;:a;{s/^/OK /}' file`. Haven't tested it with all possible solutions but the advantage that `awk` has over `sed` is that it doesn't have to use regex to solve all the problems. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '/^[^ ]\{1,\}\.\( \|$\)/ {s//OK &/;b;};s/^/NOK /' YourFile
```

assuming space are only space char (if not replace the space char by `[:space:]` or `[:blank:]` but sometimes does not accept the value on system)